# Downloaded fontawesome-pro-5.7.2 but unable to use it in my React Project

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

I have downloaded the fontawesome-pro-5.7.2. But i am seeing various folders inside of it. So i am really confused how to use the pro icons of Fontawesome in my React project. [So many folders!!! -_-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcvZ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

copy the CSS & web fonts folder into the public folder of your react project. then inside index.html file write following lines into the head tag. and you will be able to use font awesome pro icons.

```
<link href="./css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to proper give Path for fontawesome-pro-5.7.2

Don't forget to add the font-awesome CSS to index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">